# Refreshing multiple Divs on same page

Tags: jquery, refresh

Lets say I have 3 divs on my page.

```
<div id='1'></div>

<div id='2'></div>

<div id='3'></div>
```

Currently I'm using this to fresh a Div:

```
 auto_refresh = false;  
 if (auto_refresh === false) { 
   auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){$('#1').load(thisurl + '&timer=' + new Date().getTime() + ' #1' );}, 5000); 
 } else {
   clearInterval(auto_refresh); auto_refresh = false;
 }
```

And I want to refresh div 1 and 2 every 5 seconds, but not div 3.  How can I do that using Jquery? Another thing to add is, the id's of the DIVs will be dynamic.

Comment: And [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `setInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval. Also, HTML IDs are not supposed to start with numbers or special characters.

Comment: define "refresh" and source and format of refresh data

Comment: You don't need jQuery - setInterval is what you're looking for. http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: @Jasper - They can in HTML 5 (start with numbers, that is).

Comment: @DobotJr check my answer, it might be useful for you.

Comment: @deporter, yeah, might try something like that.  Gotta see what will work best.

Answer (score 1):

Like people have mentioned, you want to use `setInterval`.  One way to refresh some but not all, is to use a `class` selector, rather than an `id`.  If you must use ids, then you need to use some rule to exclude that third div.

I would then put your refresh logic into a function, and call the function from inside of the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: Good suggestion, I might just create a class for those divs that need to be refreshed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` function:

```
setInterval(function()
           { 
              $('#1').fadeOut('slow').load('your url').fadeIn("slow");
              $('#2').fadeOut('slow').load('your url').fadeIn("slow");
           }
           , 5000);
```

Comment: How would I use this if I had an array with the Divs I need to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

As far as just selecting them, and based on the (lack of other) structure, you could class them and grab "the first two":

```
<div class="c" id='1'>1</div>
<div class="c" id='2'>2</div>
<div class="c" id='3'>3</div>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('div.c:lt(2)').html("updated");

});
</script
```